# Can't import Message class and build a message in firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send the push notification using firebase FCM. I was looking for the code in firebase docs.

```
// The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
String topic = "highScores";

// See documentation on defining a message payload.
Message message = Message.builder()
    .putData("score", "850")
    .putData("time", "2:45")
    .setTopic(topic)
    .build();

// Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
// Response is a message ID string.
System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

Above is the code which I am working on. I wanted know whether we need to import Message class or create a message class. In case we want to create Message class then can you please guide me in creating a class called Message. Thank you.

I tried importing Message classes, but none of them had a builder function.

Answer (score 1):

[Message.Builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message.Builder) has a capital B, and you import it, typically just by importing Message from the Admin SDK.  Follow the provided link for API documentation.

If you're trying to send a message from an Android app, that's not supported.  You need to be using the Admin SDK on a backend server you control.

Comment: I have no idea on the concept of Admin SDK. Can you please tell more about that and can you please tell how to implement that?